# gdb is setting a breakpoint at an unexpected line

Tags: c, linux, assembly, gcc, gdb

```
1       #include <stdio.h>
2       int main()
3       {
4       int i;
5       for (i=0; i<=10; i++)
6               {
7                       puts("Hello world\n");
8               }
9               return 0;
10              //test
         }
```

I am trying to debug the code above using gdb. The problem I am facing is that when I use the command `break main`, it sets the breakpoint at line 5 rather then setting the breakpoint at line 2 where it should be. Below is the output that I am getting:

```
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x555555555141: file firstprogram.c, line 5.
```

I was expecting that the breakpoint would be set at line no 2 rather than line no 5.

Comment: Could you explain why do you think that's a problem?

Comment: Line 5 is the first line with executable code in `main`. It is, for all practical purposes, where `main` starts.

Comment: @LHLaurini I am following a book and there it places the breakpoint at main and it sets it at line 2. But when i tried it, it sets it at line 5. It should place it before main executes as I read in the book.

Comment: *It should place it before main executes as I read in the book.*  Why?  `main()` is translated to an address in memory when your code is compiled, linked, and then run, and that address is the first executable code in the `main()` C function - there's nothing "before" that that's part of `main()`.

Comment: gdb ignores the function prologue when you set a breakpoint with the function name. Maybe it didn't do that some time ago. You can set the breakpoint to the actual function beginning with `break *main`.

Answer (score 3):

You can only set a breakpoint at an address where there's an instruction.

Look at how your compiler turns this C function into asm.  (e.g. on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBJcpAAOqAqETgwe3r56icmOAkEh4SxRMVxxdpgOqUIETMQE6T5%2BZZj2uQzVtQT5YZHRsbY1dQ2ZZYNdwT1FfaUAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMzByN5YANQma24KBPioAHQI%2B9gmGgCCwQQ7LEzBEDPXNyYA7Fa39zt4%2Bx%2BN34xB2EABawAIhpAf99m59pCuDC1hY4ZZrG9bjscbicV8gXiicSdvEvAQFBBzGYABItWioHYAdxItHQJgArG4GNS3qj3iS9p9IQKScRMARFgwdijCSSAPTygiYI7vL6QjhzWicDm8PwcLSkVCcBEYyw7BQLJaYPZmNY8UgETSauYAaxAazWp0%2BAA4AGxmDkATmRQcDAb9%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%2BGQ0RxHQz7MJUdRT10NZ9EMYwiMsEiIjIuLKOozh6OAZi1OcCBXD0uJAgmfjpnEnJUgxvHhIYIzcfKeT2jGQnybaRTxgKaT9Kp5SxIM%2BnJmM0yrQskyct1JNbM4ezHOcnYtjBzyOVODRpd8/AiFBdYTJCyqIqimLKCs3LYxAQqBdPUrbHK0KXXij0vRS4MzDSjQMqynK1hsg3OBVnMqsLCAkGa%2BrKyaks6r6etGzPNtO27PqEMG0dohG6dxrXSb4/XTdtwWkt92Wo8T2288wa23gdrvB9T0O5BXxOwRP3On8/zXACbpCkCwJ4R6oJg8O3smv6UJ%2B6Q/sUAGcJAJs2sIs0bAumGKKo1IaPow0abYtGOMJrGGa0wT8ZElnN%2BJ0ntLk2nmYyVnD/Uzp96Z3Sd9GC/scZ3mzOtSy%2BadlMhYcv0nJctyPK8nyIB%2BQVoFZWFU3Zug9GYU4fouCfF9FwP0Gggx%2Bh9Mgv0HIcp5WKkaF2RssyqxymYN%2BJVcEm3CqQe8442KSCAA%3D%3D%3D) targeting Linux with current GCC/clang.)

In GCC or clang output, with or without optimization, there are instructions for the function prologue (pushing a call-preserved register or making a stack frame with a frame pointer, respectively).  The debug info generated by GCC and clang associates those instructions with the opening `{`, line 3.

(The Godbolt compiler explorer's colour syntax highlighting and mouseover highlighting is based on the debug info generated by compilers, the same info GDB uses when mapping source lines to/from addresses.)

The first instruction for anything in the function body is either the `i=0` in the unoptimized version, or the `mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0` / `call    puts` in the loop body.

(GCC/clang consider the `mov ebx, 11` loop counter init to not be associated with a source line, since after optimization they've transformed the loop into counting down to zero for 11 iterations.  That mov-to-register instruction is part of the function prologue, according to the debug info.)